# The path when using the route name is incorrect Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

`web.php` in routes folder:

```
Route::get('contact-us', function (){return 'hello everyone';})->name('contact');
```

and `test.php` in views folder:

```
<a href="{{route('contact')}}"> Go to Contact page </a>
```

But when I click the link in the browser it shows the wrong address:

```
http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Broute('contact')%7D%7D
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:9000/contact-us
```

This is my screen:

[image]

Comment: To use blade syntax, files must end in `.blade.php`. So if the file is names `test.php`, you won't be able to use blade syntax. Rename your file to `test.blade.php` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your view:

`<a href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact us</a>`